# Сайт проиндексирован в гугле, но не показывается в поиске

Tags: seo, google-search

Столкнулся с проблемой после обновления сайта, сначала в поиске выходили старые страницы, которых уже нет.

Запросил удаление, подождал, все исчезло, потом снова запросил индексирование, что бы просканировались новые страницы... Поменял сайтмап и т.д, но в поиске не появляется :(

Яндекс поиск работает шикарно, свой сайт нахожу по ключам и по прямому запросу, с гуглом понять не могу что

Кто нибудь знает в чем проблема может быть?

P.S: Запрос на удаление отменял.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что тема продвижения сайтов в поисковых системах не входит в перечень допустимых тем на ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @МихаилРебров не думаю, что это именно про продвижение, это скорее баг

Comment: @Бодяпаук в чем именно? Он сам запросил удаление. Ему все удалили. Теперь ждёт индексации. С учетом исхода Гугла из России желаю ему удачи в этом. У меня он в принципе перестал нормально искать по рунету в последнее время. Так что по-моему автор просто выбрал не самое удачное время для удаления своих страниц. Мог просто редиректы поставить.